# Allow HTML tags in wordpress shortcode content?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I have a simple shortcode which takes an attribute and some content and returns an html block:

```
function testimonial($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "by" => 'Joe'
), $atts));
return '<p class="testimonial">'.$content.'<br /><span>&mdash; '.$by.'</span></p>';
}
add_shortcode("testimonial", "testimonial");
```

and the poster can include a shortcode such as:

```
[testimonial by="Bob Smith"]This was great![/testimonial]
```

My question is, how to allow the user to insert simple html tags such as `<b>` or `<br/>` in their content, such as:

```
[testimonial by="Bob Smith"]Excellent restaurant.<br/>Try the desserts![/testimonial]
```

Since the function currently returns "content" as a string, the code  displays.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow your own interpretation of short codes, for example if user types `[b]` you can replace it in the output as `<strong>` or `<b>`. I.e. `$content` can be

```
str_replace("[b]","<strong>", $content);
```

This is just rough example of the idea.